# Заполнение двумерного массива Python 3.6

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x, матрицы

Всем привет, я не прошу готового решения, мне просто нужна подсказка, возможно ли написать программу, которая бы заполняла матрицу сохраняя тот же рисунок, что описан ниже? То есть данные могут быть разные, но рисунок тот же. Если да, то как?

```
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   3
4   2   1   1   1   1   1   5
4   4   2   1   1   1   6   7
4   4   4   2   1   8   9   10
4   4   4   3   1   11  12  13
4   4   3   1   1   1   14  15
4   3   1   1   1   1   1   16
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
```

Comment: Возможно ли заполнение именно такими фигурами или все-таки брать  построчное заполнение?

Comment: Может быть создать новый массив, затем сделать два цикла (for i... for j...), затем рассмотреть условия (i-j больше/меньше нуля) и (i+j больше/меньше n)

Comment: Дмитрий, дело в том, что значения могут быть различны, тут все дело в рисунке..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пример заполнения правого сектора

```
  entry_point = 5
for i in range(1, array_size - 1):  # заполнение правого сектора от 5 до 16
    if i < array_size // 2:
        for j in range(array_size - i, array_size):
            array[i][j] = entry_point
            entry_point += 1
    else:
        for j in range(i + 1, array_size):
            array[i][j] = entry_point
            entry_point += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут похоже одномерный массив из любых можно развернуть в двумерный простым перебором.

```
PATTERN = [[2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3],
[4,  2,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  5],
[4,  4,  2,  1,  1,  1,  6,  7],
[4,  4,  4,  2,  1,  8,  9,  10],
[4,  4,  4,  3,  1,  11, 12, 13],
[4,  4,  3,  1,  1,  1,  14, 15],
[4,  3,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  16],
[3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2]]

INPUT = list(range(17)) #любые числа записать в этот массив

OUTPUT = []

for y in range(8):
    OUTPUT.append([])
    for x in range(8):
        OUTPUT[y].append(INPUT[PATTERN[y][x]])

print(OUTPUT)
```

Comment: присмотритесь, вот где единицы написаны, там нарисован треугольник, где четверки трапеция, вот о сохранении этих рисунков я говорю=(

Comment: так а у меня что? код запускать пробовал? те же рисунки  остаются. вон посмотри ответ с пандасом. тоже самое делает чел только другим способом. закинь в инпут 16 циферок и выполни остальные строчки

Comment: Я наверно не правильно объясняю, этот массив, как пример рисунка, то есть такой нужно создать, а не использовать, как готовый

Comment: сейчас не стало яснее. вот по твоему шаблону рисунок создаю с другими цифрами. что не так то?)

Comment: проблема в том, что заполнение матрицы должно быть по секторам, в соответствии с рисунком

Comment: так в моём варианте матрица заполняется по секторам в соответствии с рисунком. Первое число из инпут кладется сверху и снизу в полосочки, второе бантиком.. что не так то?)

Comment: Не так то, что вы используете PATTERN, как шаблон, а нужно создать именно такой рисунок.

Comment: вы не правильно ставите вопрос) может вам надо написать алгоритм обхода этой марицы?

Answer (score 1):

Если это школьная задачка, то прочитав условие, а не ответ к ней было б проще её решить. Поиграем в угадай задание. Может имелось ввиду написать алгоритм(как олимпиадная улитка)?

```
for y in range(8):
    OUTPUT.append([])
    for x in range(8):
        if x==y and (x< 8/2 or x==8):
            OUTPUT[y].append(2)
        elif x==8-y and (y>8/2 or y==0):
            OUTPUT[y].append(3)
        elif ...
        elif ...
        else:
            OUTPUT[y].append(1)
```

Comment: Нет, это не школьная задачка, я поняла как ее сделать, нужно было просто сначала заполнить все нулями, потом заполнить левый и правый сектор, потом главную и побочную диагональ, а в конце уже заполнить все единицами...

Comment: нулями заполнять не обязательно. по диагонли  и треугольникам можно идти как в этом примере.